# How to iterate through a text file to find a specific value

Tags: python

The problem I have is that it wont return a specific value, my code just returns the first value in the text file... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `return` is inside the loop. It returns after the first iteration.

Comment: your return statement should be on the same indentation level as your for loop otherwise it will return on the first iteration

Answer (score 0):

You are returning maxValue inside loop so loop is running only once. return from function after closing file will give you correct result.

```
def fileValue(file):
    inputFile = open(file)
    maxValue = 0
    for n in inputFile:
        n = int(n.rstrip())
        if maxValue < n:
            maxValue = n
    inputFile.close()
    return maxValue
```